# Python - Having issues getting my function to loop through items in my list

Tags: python, function

Can someone help me and explain where I am going wrong with this code please?

I am working through the Python Crash Course and have tried to modify a program that greets users from a list.The issues is the output only ever works for the first name in the list.

```
#function that should greet every user in the list of users.
def greet_users(names):
    for name in names:
        msg=print(f"\nHello {name}")
        return(msg)

#How the user will quit the while loop.
print("Enter Q to exit")
total_users=[] 
#while loop to populate the list.
while True:
    user = input("Enter a user ")
    if user =="Q":
        break
    else:
        total_users.append(user)
        
greet_users(total_users)
```

Just for my piece of mind, is someone able to explain where this is going wrong?
I have a feeling it is the function itself but when I read it, I feel the for loop is the issues but at the same time, it works in the book!

Thanks!

I tried changing the while loop to see if it was not populating the list. When entering three names and just printing the list, it does in fact fill it in.

Which leads me to think the problem is the function but I am unsure on what part. The for loop was my initial thought however the book uses the exact same loop and it works.

Comment: Try printing the name in the loop as you get it from the user.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement inside of your for loop causes the function to exit.

Also, the `print` function always returns `None`, so you don't need to save it to a variable.

```
def greet_users(names):
    for name in names:
        print(f"\nHello {name}")
```